# Square Root of a second degree polynomial

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, integers

I need to know for what value of $x \in \mathbb{N}$ does the polynomial $ax^2+bx+c$ with $ a,b,c\in\mathbb{N}$ equal the square of an integer.

If you prefer, i need to know what value of $x$ will be such that: $\sqrt(ax^2+bx+c)\in\mathbb{N}$.

All values of $x,a,b,c$ are positive integers.

The polynomial which interests me in particular is :
$36*x^2 + 56*x +7995453861842103882252425822275998412699202362448924475307930928937402245230$$6617291822428065342048965758784902772389802103317323879735383364538768000809388$$8076376978587530748441268705252251321819446107980521240564179264428788411121925$$6066387564920446441587889602731879796883465273468350191838480313574299986165758$$2471484858434279354060689373075538037635386382754674888158184275820269791090709$$0556741645605740041922895133513297361792649349289314878268328070492465568295282$$7171309360023249573906359278643008610907917524964403251540395970322124616479375$$74211098337827262669280820216819848507154579112266346980235635617$

I'm trying to solve a second degree diophantine equation $at^2+(b+cx)t+(d+ex)=0$, which gives me $\triangle = \sqrt(36*x^2 + 56*x +7995453861842103882252425822275998412699202362448924475307930928937402245230$$6617291822428065342048965758784902772389802103317323879735383364538768000809388$$8076376978587530748441268705252251321819446107980521240564179264428788411121925$$6066387564920446441587889602731879796883465273468350191838480313574299986165758$$2471484858434279354060689373075538037635386382754674888158184275820269791090709$$0556741645605740041922895133513297361792649349289314878268328070492465568295282$$7171309360023249573906359278643008610907917524964403251540395970322124616479375$$74211098337827262669280820216819848507154579112266346980235635617)$

Comment: This issue was discussed there.   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1139749/can-we-predict-when-a-polynomial-can-take-more-than-one-perfect-square-value/1140770#1140770

Comment: I am curious to know why that particular polynomial interests you.

Comment: I added a second part to the question to explain why this polynomial interests me, Gerry.